# This Python code works in online compiler but not in spyder

Tags: python, spyder

This code works in online Python compiler but not in Spyder ( I'm only allowed to use Spyder for my exam).
A few cases do not work (like in with method after printing "insufficient fund" it waits for me to put long input)

This is the question:

> Design a class named Account that contains: A private int data field
> named accountno for the account. A private float data field named
> balance for the account. A constructor that creates an account with
> the specified accountno and Initial balance (default 100). A method
> named withdraws that withdraws a specified amount from the account. A
> minimum  balance of 100 should be maintained for each account. A
> method named deposit that deposits a specified amount to the specific
> account. Write a program that maintains ‘n’ number of Account objects
> with unique accountno and supports  following operations.  a) New
> account creation  b) deposit operation for a given account no c)
> withdraw operation for a given account no d) Display account no with
> highest balance

This is the code which I wrote:

```
class bank ():
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.__balance=100
        self.__accno=a 
    def depo (self,d):
        self.__balance+=d
        print("current balnce ",self.__balance)
    def withd(self,w):
        if w>=self.__balance:
            print("inssuficinet fund ")
        else :
            self.__balance-=w
            print("current balnce ",self.__balance)
    def getbal(self):
        return self.__balance
    def getacc (self):
        return self.__accno 
    
l1=[]#accno
l2=[]#obj 
l3=[]#max 

f=True 
while(f):
    c=int(input("1.create 2.deposit 3.withdraw 4.display max "))
    if c==1:
        a=int(input("enter the account number "))
        if a in l1:
            print("account ni already present  ")
        else:
            l1.append(a)
            l2.append(bank(a))
            
    if c==2:
        try:
            a=int(input("enter the account number "))
            i=l1.index(a)
            d=int(input("enter the amount to be deposited "))
            l2[i].depo(d)
        except:
            print("not found")
    if c==3:
        try:
            a=int(input("enter the account number "))
            i=l1.index(a)
            w=int(input("enter the amount to be withdrawed "))
            l2[i].withd(w)
        except:
            print("not found")
        
            
    
    if c==4:
        if len(l1)==0:
            print("no account found ")
        else :
            for i in l2:
                l3.append(i.getbal())
            j=l3.index(max(l3))
            print("acc with max bal is ",l2[j].getacc())
            l3=[]
    if c==5:
        f=False
```

Comment: I don't know Spyder at all, but it is possible that your version of spyder is using an older version of python (ie 2.x rather than 3.x) where the online compiler might be using a newer one.

In python 2, using the parentheses for the print function is likely to print a tuple rather than just the string inside the parentheses.

Comment: What version of Spyder are you using? If you are using Spyder 5.1.5 with Anaconda maybe this issue could be worthy a check: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17616

The latest Spyder version is 5.3.1 so you will need to update to it following the steps described here https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17616#issuecomment-1088750490

Answer (score 0):

Hi dear @Raksha Kamath **I tested** your code and it looks like everything is **working fine**, the problem is probably your **Spider IDE**.

```py
gedflod@localhost:~/home$ python3 m.py
```

#### Outputs

```bash
1.create 2.deposit 3.withdraw 4.display max 1
enter the account number 45
1.create 2.deposit 3.withdraw 4.display max 7
1.create 2.deposit 3.withdraw 4.display max 9
1.create 2.deposit 3.withdraw 4.display max 3
enter the account number 56
not found
1.create 2.deposit 3.withdraw 4.display max
```

---

I will recommend you try a different IDE (like [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/), PyIDLE etc...)